# mongodb replicaset new member does not show the correct disk usage on EC2

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a mongodb replicaset with 2 members. 1 primary and 1 secondary. if I issue `show dbs`, both of them are show like followings:

```
local   24.06640625GB
test    0.203125GB
db1     9.94921875GB
db1test 0.953125GB
```

and then I issue `use db1` -> `db.events.count()`, the result return `1003130` documents on both of the members.

that makes sense they reflecting to each other and db1 and db1test on both of dbserver have the same amount of disk usage and the same amount of document in each collection.

then I decide to add a new member(a new dbserver) which has an empty /data/db. I start the new server by using:

```
sudo mongod --replSet rs0 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log
```

then in primary server, I issue

```
rs.add('ipOfNewDBServer:27017')
```

After a few seconds. my new mongodb server shell change from `>` -> `STARTUP2` -> `rs0:SECONDARY` which I think start sync.

In the new/recent added mongodb server I issue `show dbs`, it looks like the following:

```
local   22.0673828125GB
test    0.203125GB
db1     1.953125GB
db1test 0.453125GB
```

the disk usage of each database are not as the same as the other two(1 primary and 1 secondary). however, if I issue `use db1` -> `db.events.count()`, the result return `1003130` which are the same as the other two. and I check the other collections in this db1. they all the same.

I wonder why database disk usage are different and the collection in each of database have the same amount of documents??? and correct me if I did anything wrong to sync the data from those two existing set to the new set. the mongodb offical document says `This procedure relies on MongoDB’s regular process for initial sync`, I have no ideas, please help. thanks

Comment: Mongo preallocates chunks of disk space for the DBs, and can end up with fragmentation in a given file if documents are deleted. Differing sizes is normal and expected.

Comment: @ChrisHeald what do you mean end up with fragmentation in a give file if documents are deleted. the new server does not have any file when i create it until it starts sync. can you explain more or any document that i can read. are the collections in each database are syncing correctly?? thanks

Comment: Mongo allocates chunks of disk space for its data files. Documents that get updated get moved to the end of the chunk if it would grow beyond its already-allocated size. Documents that get deleted get deleted. Both leave "holes" in the allocated files - that is, fragmentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new member of the replica set will have the benefit of no fragmentation as he full synchronizes to the replset.  The existing replicase, very likely, have fragmentation due to deletes and document updates moving the documents.

In our environment, we periodically take each member of the replset offline, whack its data directory, and allow it to full sync to drive out fragmentation.  It works for us, but our dataset may be "small" relative to other deployments.  I think there is a way to do this through the console with some db.runCommand but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Ok, so you mean the existing replicasets have fragmentation so that it makes the disk usage so big and the new one is clean and no fragmentation. but the data/documents sync correctly? right?

Comment: @eded Yes, when you do the full sync into an empty data directory the new one is clean with no fragmentation.